# Read-only sharing rule is not restricting editing from inline-editing, whereas from API it is getting restricted

Tags: apex, visualforce, sharing, inlineeditsupport

I have 2 user groups **K1** and **NK1**. **NK1 are managers of K1**.Custom object **A_S** has OWD **private**, with grant access. There is a sharing rule to give read-only access to K1 users of NK1 user's records. It works fine from workbench, while K1 tries to update NK1 record, it throws error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY. But from a visualforce page, that uses **inline-editing** K1 can edit NK1 records. How can I restrict such scenarios? inline-editing code part :

`<apex:column >
 <apex:outputField value="{!k.Abv_Core_KAM_January__c}" id="January" > 
   <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"   showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" hideOnEdit="AddMoreButton"/> 
 </apex:outputfield>
</apex:column>`

Comment: If you say NK1 are managers of K1 would you want to create a role hierarchy rather than a group which is basically a flat organisation type?

Comment: Hi @Mihai Neagoe there is a role-hierarchi in place along with group

Answer (score 2):

You need to enforce the sharing rules in the custom controller definition or in the standard controller extension:

**Enforcing Sharing Rules in Controllers**
Like other Apex classes, custom controllers and controller extensions run in system mode.
Typically, you want a controller or controller extension to respect a user’s organization-wide defaults, role hierarchy, and sharing rules. You can do that by using the with sharing keywords in the class definition. For information, see “Using the with sharing or without sharing Keywords” in the Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide.
http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_controller.htm

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, when you try and update the record of NK1 from a K1 user. The sharing rule you have only gives Read access, I suggest changing the sharing rule into a Read/Write permission.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: but i want to restrict editing, why should i give read/write in sharing rule? which works fine from workbench but with inline editing it is able to edit

Comment: I see, have you looked at field level security for the K1 user?